# Unlikely argument type for equals(): String seems to be unrelated to char[]

Tags: java, passwords

So, I am writing code for a username password to be input when prompted. I am struggling with pulling the password from the user input and comparing it to what the username/password should be. I have this for when the submit button is pushed:

```java
char[] password = passwordInput.getPassword();
                String username = usernameInput.getText();

                try {
                    if (username.equals(user1) && password.equals(password1)) {
                        
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success");
                    }

                    else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username/password!");

                    }
```

and I also initialized the correct username and pasword in the begining of the script with
`String user1 = "uccs", password1 = "1234";`

im not sure if I need to convert the passwordInput to a String? I tried `char password = 1234;` but that didn't work either.

Comment: `new String(password).equals(password1)`

Comment: i have the string initializes right about it. the "password" your iniitializing is the user input which is the ``char[] password = passwordInput.getPassword(); ``